# How to do core data fetch predicate for NSDate in swift? i want to filter it by months

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

// fetching data

```
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", txtUsername.text!)

    do {
        let results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        if (results.count > 0){
            var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
            txtname.text = res.valueForKey("name") as! String
            txtPassword.text = res.valueForKey("password") as! String

            print(results.count)
```

have no idea how to predicate NSdate, my entity have three attributes and one of is of  date type so if any body knows then do please tell me with an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using NSDate within an NSPredicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317240/using-nsdate-within-an-nspredicate)

Comment: want it in swift brother

Comment: The predicates are identical in Objectives-C and Swift.

Comment: i want to predicate it by a particular month ? how to do that ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

Get the first date and last date of a month and then use it like

```
let startDate = NSDate().startOfMonth()
let endDate = NSDate().endOfMonth()
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateField >= %@ AND dateField <= %@", startDate!, endDate!)
```

Where startDate and endDate are NSDate variables. This will get you data for current month. Similarly you can use it for other months too.

You can use below code to get start and end date of month

```
extension NSDate {

    func startOfMonth() -> NSDate? {

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let currentDateComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: self)
        let startOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(currentDateComponents)

        return startOfMonth
    }

    func dateByAddingMonths(monthsToAdd: Int) -> NSDate? {

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let months = NSDateComponents()
        months.month = monthsToAdd

        return calendar.dateByAddingComponents(months, toDate: self, options: [])
    }

    func endOfMonth() -> NSDate? {

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        if let plusOneMonthDate = dateByAddingMonths(1) {
            let plusOneMonthDateComponents = calendar.components([.Year, .Month], fromDate: plusOneMonthDate)

            let endOfMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(plusOneMonthDateComponents)?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1)

            return endOfMonth
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this before but getting an error , can you tell me exactly  where to put this ? @AnkitaShah

Comment: do i need to put this outside of my class ? @AnkitaShah

Comment: It's a NSDate extension. So put it at the end of code. I'm editing the answer with example

Comment: Yes. Extension will be outside of class

Comment: throwing an error on  this line -      request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateField >= %@ AND dateField <= %@", startDate!, endDate!)    use of unresolved identifier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95999/discussion-between-abhinaman-abhi-and-ankita-shah).